# How to write junit test for ListenableFuture callback

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, concurrent.futures

I'm looking for direction and guidance on how can i write junit test for listenable futures callback method -

```
class Service {

public ResultSetFuture execute(Statement statement) {

    ResultSetFuture results = super.execute(statement);
    processCallBack(results);
    return results;
}


private void processCallBack(ResultSetFuture resultSetFuture) {

    // process callback on different thread

    Futures.addCallback(resultSetFuture, new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@Nullable final ResultSet result) {

            // some logic
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@Nonnull final Throwable t) {
            // some logic
        }
    }, this.futureCallBackExecutorService);
}
```

}

More specifically write jUnit tests for onSuccess and onFailure method on callback in different thread.